# What do the lap colors in the iOS stopwatch mean?

Tags: ios, clock

I've done a fair bit of Googling, checking Apple's website, etc., but can't figure out what the red and green colors present on certain laps in the clock app's stopwatch represent.

Perhaps it's a common feature of digital stopwatches I'm unaware of?

[image: Image showing the colored laps]

Comment: It's not something I've seen elsewhere, but seeing the colours used and comparing the lap times I guess they though it was self-explanatory

Comment: Yeah, it's quite obvious now that it's been pointed out 

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The **green** lap is the **fastest** lap, i.e. the shortest duration of any lap.

The **red** lap is the **slowest** lap, i.e. the longest duration of any lap.

If you use VoiceOver or Speak Screen to verbalise the content, or other accessibility functionality like a Braille keyboard, these rows are read out with the suffix ‘fastest’ and ‘slowest’ respectively after the time.

Comment: This screams for an additional label next to the duration. What a strange UX miss.